# How do I restore a Windows 7 DMG file to Boot Camp (and make it bootable)?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, disk-utility, dmg

My iMac's HD died last week, and so I was unable to access OS X (I had a Time Machine backup of it though). Fortunately I was able to boot into the Recovery HD and use Disk Utility to backup Boot Camp to a DMG file on an external drive before I lost that forever.

So, now I have a DMG file containing Windows 7. From what I understand, it's much more difficult to restore Windows Vista/7 than it is to restore Windows XP because the boot method has gotten more complex.

However, could someone point me in the right direction in order to restore a Windows 7 DMG file to Boot Camp, and of course make it bootable? I already tried the method [shown here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10835653#10835653), which is quoted at a lot of places, but it definitely only works with WinXP and nothing newer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I made an attempt using the method you quoted. I was not able to restore the partition as bootable. The partition was restored (Takes a while to scan and restore) and it's contents were accessible from the mac side. Using the script didn't add it to the boot list.
Would reinstalling Win7 so it's bootable, then pushing the image over that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variation on what its stated there:

1. Run bootcamp to allocate the space 2-
2. Install W7
3. Go back to OSX (Install REFIT or similar as bootmanager (optional))
4. Restore your DMG image over the W7 partition

With this you dont need the fdisk commands as bootcamp should mark the partition as active (bootable).

This *SHOULD* work.

The problem with the linked page process is that w7 (just as osx) is actually in 2 partitions, a small boot one and a large with the OS, your DMG only contains the OS partition.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue of losing my disk with OS X and Bootcamped Win7.  I was able to make a .DMG of the "Bootcamp" "partition" as well.  I have tried:

-Going through the bootcamp setup just far enough that it created my necessary partitions and then imaging the .DMG onto the correct partition

-Installing a fresh copy of windows so that it booted from the new installation and then imaging the .DMG over that

Neither of these worked for me.  The first option gave me a couple of problems: holding "Option" would not show me a windows bootable device, and choosing the windows option in system preferences>startup disk gave me an error stating it couldn't find a bootable disk.  The second option gives me both a bootable disk under startup disk and a windows option when holding "Option" on bootup, but either way, I only get a blinking cursor when it attempts to boot the windows partition :-(

I'm wondering if it would be easier to just totally start over, or if there's a way to fix the MBR which will still save me the time of setting up all my data again....

More research...

Comment: You've posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked.

Comment: I think what I ultimately did was use iPartition to fix the MBR boot code for the Boot Camp partition, after having restored the DMG to it using Disk Utility. iPartition has some "secret sauce" that fixes MBR boot codes, and it did the trick for me. I purchased the product a few months before that so I didn't have to buy it again. So yeah, unfortunately, it isn't a free option, but it's what I used.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent long time on this and finally found a work around to restore DMG image file of windows 7 to a partition on mac drive and then boot in to widows holding option ket at start up or in startup option.

Just didn't want to type loads, as this is an old post and maybe everyone else has found away too.

Cheers

Danny

Comment: This answer isn't very clear.

Comment: Danny, I'm in the same boat now and can't figure it out - what did you do!?!